# Элемент удаляется раньше чем применяется эффект

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему так происходит, а именно, при использовании метода **remove()** после метода **fadeTo(1500, 0)** (*цепной стиль вызова методов*), элемент удаляется раньше чем применяется эффект.

[Код jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuNF5/2/)

Comment: Внутри callback-функции [удаляйте][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/XuNF5/4/

Comment: @Deonis спасибо! и как говорят у вас Одессе, таки да! )

Comment: Потому что fadeTo не выполняется синхронно, а просто ставит анимацию в очередь (которая, на самом деле, тоже не умеет выполняться синхронно). Поэтому fadeTo работает не 1500 мс, а насколько получится быстро (что логично, потому что иначе последующий код бы не выполнялся еще долгое время).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".Chavyk").on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this)
    $this.fadeTo(1500, 0, function(){ $(this).remove(); });
});
```

P.S> Так и не проще использовать [fadeOut](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Появление_и_иcчезновение_элементов_за_счет_прозрачности)?

Comment: @Олег Б спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь очередностью. В jQuery API это **[.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)** Ваш обновленный **[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/XuNF5/3/)**.

```
$(".fadeStayInDOM").on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeTo(1500, 0);
});

$(".Chavyk").on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeTo(1500, 0).queue(function () {
        $(this).remove();
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Comment: @VenZell спасибо, плюсанул, но функция с callback мне показалась проще ;)